# Add to cart product using ajax magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9

How can add to cart  product using ajax on Magento 1.9.2.4 
after adding to cart item update on cart items by ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to cart product using ajax magento 1.9 GitHub so please check it.

https://github.com/manishiitg/excellence_magento_blog/tree/master/Ajax%20Add%20Cart%20Module

Comment: its not working proper.

Comment: @jay - what is the issue, I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is free of cost you can install and it is working fine.

https://www.magestore.com/magento-ajax-cart-extension.html

Comment: allow only PDF download on this link not extension